# Angular datepicker is not working in angular-xeditable "Editable table row"

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm trying to add angular calendar in angular-xeditable "Editable table row" but it's not working.
Here is the link :

```
*http://jsfiddle.net/176m690o/*
```

When I click on the edit button for any row then first column just shows a input box but when I click on it then no pop-up for selecting a date.

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Hi, take a look at my answer here, It's exactly like your example and the fiddle is working... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36779447/466275 ... Don't forget to check any missing external resources and put angular as a framework as I explained. Then compare the rest of the code.